# Is it possible to override property's method?

Tags: objective-c

I need to add some codes when MyClass's string value is changed.
So I'm trying to override a MyClass's string property method.
But I have no idea.. so I do like following.
Is it correct?

How to override property's method?

```
@interface MyClass{
     NSString *string;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@end


@implementation MyClass

- (void)setString:(NSString*)newString{
    // want to add some codes.

    [self setString:newString];  <= Is this correct?
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)setString:(NSString*)newString{
    // want to add some codes.

    string = newString;  //This is the setter method!
    // You will need to consider memory management etc. 
}
```

What you are probably more up to is this:

```
- (void)setString:(NSString*)newString{
    // want to add some codes.

    [super setString:newString];  
}
```

`[self setString:newString]` at this place would be a an endless recursive loop. `[super setString:newString]` should call the superlass' setter. However, I never did that myself.

Comment: I think above code doesn't consider property's argument. e.g.) retain, copy, nonatomic etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll mend the answer. I think I understand now what you are up to.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not to override (no subclass are involve in your code snippet).

What is in your  code is just the  declaration `@interface` and the definition `@implementation`. It have the same meaning and utility to the declaration/definition in C where you put declaration in a `.h` file and definition in a `.c` file.

Assuming that your are speaking of how to synthesize, your code is almost correct. You are just missing the getter `- (NSString *) string;` or you what it readonly.

As for how to do correctly the assignment you should use the `=`

```
- (void)setString:(NSString*)newString{
    // want to add some codes.

    string = newString;  // Correct way of doing it
}
```

There is 2 way to synthesize a propertie, either by defining the setter and getter by hand or either by using the syntactic sugar `@synthesize`.

For a better understanding consider that `@property` and `@synthesize` are both syntactic sugar. (Only that `@property` is adding some semantic with the retain, strong, etc.. keyword).

Better is to read the documentation that you can found. There is many easy to found web page where you could have more details.